# Transmission line current magnitude

Tags: power, transmission-line, power-engineering

I want to compute the current magnitude in a transmission line. The line has properties `b` (total line charging susceptance, p.u.), `x` (reactance, p.u.), and `r` (resistance, p.u.). I'm confused about what value of resistance I need to use in Ohm's law and the difference between `b`, `x`, and `r` parameters.

When I compute the flow magnitude (section [4.1.1](https://ideas.repec.org/p/mns/wpaper/wp201214.html)) as

\$
|y_{\text{snd},\text{rec}}| \times |V_{\text{snd}} e^{jA_{\text{snd}}} -  V_{\text{rec}} e^{jA_{\text{rec}}}|
\$

where \$V_{\text{snd}}\$ is the voltage magnitude at the "sending" bus and \$A_{\text{snd}}\$ is the voltage angle at the "sending" bus (and `rec` denotes "receiving" bus), how do I compute the magnitude of the branch admittance, \$|y_{\text{snd},\text{rec}}|\$, from `b`, `x`, and `r`?

I'm confused because if \$y_{\text{snd},\text{rec}}\$`= r / (r^2 + x^2) - j x / (r^2 + x^2)`, then what is the purpose of the line charging `b`? Or is \$y_{\text{snd},\text{rec}}\$`= 1/b`?

Comment: This site supports limited TeX (I believe specifically Mathjax), which would help make your equations more readable.

Comment: Your notation: from/to etc, is confusing. Also, the two ends of a transmission line are normally referred to as the 'sending end', SE, and 'receiving end', RE.

Comment: @Chu: ok, i replace from/to with send/receive